# XPATH 1.0: compare IP addresses

Tags: xml, xpath

In XPATH 1.0, I'd like to compare two IP addresses that appear as strings. Is it feasible ?

For example, I'd like to check whether a given IP address is lower than another, as in `8.8.8.8 < 8.8.8.9`.

Comment: Well, not really. For instance, you can't define an IP address range just by throwing two random IP addresses. It doesn't seem to me so bizarre as you put it. Look at this built-in library in Python implementing a comparison between IP addresses https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#comparison-operators

Answer (score -1):

There are some function can help you do that:

1. [Function: string translate(string, string, string)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) 
   you can use this function to remove the `.` in the IP address
2. [Function: number number(object?)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number)
   this function will convert the string to the number, then you can compare them.